# Enable test mode in RevMob

Tags: android, sdk, revmob

How to enable test mode in RevMob Android? I'm trying to find code snippet but not able to find.

```
revmob.setTestingMode(RevMobTestingMode.WITH_ADS);
```

The above code is not working.

My app is not in live. Its just in testing purpose. The following pic is showing what they are saying to implement.
[See here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ufaW.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The setTestingMode isn't used anymore and will soon be removed. To get test ads just use your media ID that has "Testing" as status.

Comment: Thanks fro help. But im getting error "Fullscreen not received. Ad not received: RevMob did not answer as expected. (431)" Do you know why ?

Comment: Are you using any proxies?

Comment: I see. Could you send us the output of revmob.printEnvironmentInformation(this);? This would be really useful to help you solve your problem